# ELF and virtual address in C

Tags: assembly, architecture, elf, virtual-address-space

I am studying for a test, and I have the following question:
In the ELF header it is said that the file's entry point is at  0x8049058

the code is:

```
section .data
    x: dd 3

    _start: mov ecx, [x]
    ...
    ...
    ... ;more code
```

Q: what will be the virtual address of x at run time?

the correct answer is 0x0849054

can someone please shed light on this? 
If x would be as followd, will it still be in the same address?

```
section .bss
x: resb 4

section .data

_start: mov ecx, [x]
...
...
... ;more code
```

where exacly does an entry point "Take" me?
And what sections are close to it?

Answer (score 3):

If you are pedantic, there is not enough information to tell. If we assume that `_start` is the entry point (which is typical, but not mandatory) then given that the size of `x` is 4 bytes, and there is nothing else between `x` and `_start`, then the address of `x` is obviously `_start - 4`. Note that it is not normal to have the entry point in the `.data` section.

For the second code, you have no way to tell where `.bss` is in relation to `.data` or `_start`, unless you examine the headers in the binary.

Comment: is it ok to asume that all the variables in the .data section will be exacly "above" the entry? since it is in the same section?

Comment: Yes, they are not reordered within the section.